# Javascript works in Chrome, Safari and Opera but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

[Site here.](http://saucydares.freehostia.com/saucy.php)

Basically the box in the middle doesn't generate random string from my database in Firefox as it does in the other browsers. I can't seem to find the problem, my JS skills aren't amazing.

I haven't tested it in IE as I don't have access to it right now.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `form` is not defined where you're using it in firefox, you could write it a bit differently to be cross-browser compatible like this:

```
function get() {
  $('#dare').fadeOut(500);

  $.post ('data.php', $("form").serialize(), function(output) {
    $('#dare').html(output).fadeIn(500);
  });
}
```

The [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function will take every input element in the form a serialize it, resulting in the same request all the other browsers are making...in a lot less code :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the error message in firebug:

```
form is not defined

$.post ('data.php', {name: form.name.value, mode: mode, player: player},
```

Answer (score 0):

The following error is generated when you view the site in Firefox:

> Error: form is not defined
>   Source File: http://saucydares.freehostia.com/saucy.php
>   Line: 29

The line in question is

```
$.post ('data.php', {name: form.name.value, mode: mode, player: player},
```

I think the correct method for what you're doing here (if I interpret what you're doing here correctly) is to obtain the form's name with jQuery.